# Android: Textview below Imageview in TouchImageview

Tags: android, textview, imageview, touch

I'm making an application with TouchImageView of Mike Ortiz. The works ok with the image in the center to full screen. But I want to add a textview below each picture with the description of the image. But I can not. The images move and textview not always appear below the image. This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<imagenes.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why you gave fill-parent to your image view ??
Use ScrollView....

Comment: with fill_parent and match_parent the result is same

Comment: I know..

BUt why are you using fill-parent/match-parent to your imageview???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

why you using `layout_height="fill_parent"` for the `imageview`?   use `match_parent` instead and `relativeLayout`  comes with handy attributes such as `layout_below , layout_above`  compare my answer with yours and you'll see the differences.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <imagenes.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgDisplay"
    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it not works. textview not appears. but if I remove android:layout_below the textview appears on top screen

Comment: @MayankSaini i guess you have no idea what is match_parent and fill_parent are... 
OP:  what software u using to program android ?

Comment: @user3327667 use wrap_content for the imageview instead

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I guess you're not using the latest version of `TouchImageView`. There is a new one (1.0) at:

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java

Using this in combination with a `LinearLayout` and `android:weightSum`+`android:layout_weight` you can achieve exactly what you are heading for. I also prefer using a `ScrollView` along with the `TextView` for longer texts (short texts aren't affected by it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <imagenes.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/some_description"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

enjoy :)